# Word frequency counter

Tags: python, python-2.x

I recently took a self-assessment question to assess my Python ability for an online class. The problem was to return the frequency of a word occurring, as part of a tuple.

> Implement a function count_words() in Python that takes as input a
>   string `word_string` and a number `number_of_words`, and returns the n most frequently-occurring words in `word_string`. The return value should be a list of tuples - the top n
>   words paired with their respective counts [(, ), (,
>   ), ...], sorted in descending count order.
>
> You can assume that all input will be in lowercase and that there will
>   be no punctuations or other characters (only letters and single
>   separating spaces). In case of a tie (equal count), order the tied
>   words alphabetically.
>
> E.g.: `print count_words("this is an example sentence with a repeated word example",3)` Output: `[('example', 2), ('a', 1), ('an', 1)]`

```
def count_words(word_string, number_of_words):
  """
  take in a word string and return a tuple of the
  most frequently counted words

  word_string = "This is an example sentence with a repeated word example",
  number_of_words = 3
  return [('example', 2), ('This', 1), ('a', 1)]
  """
  word_array = word_string.split(' ')
  word_occurence_array = []
  for word in word_array:
    if word in word_string:
      occurence_count = word_array.count(word)
      word_occurence_array.append((word, occurence_count))
    else:
      # no occurences, count = 0
      word_occurence_array.append((word, 0))

  # dedupe
  word_occurence_array = list(set(word_occurence_array))

  # reorder
  # can also pass, reverse=True, but cannot apply `-` to string
  word_occurence_array.sort(key=lambda tup: (-tup[1], tup[0]))

  # only return the Nth number of pairs
  return word_occurence_array[:number_of_words]
```

You can then call this function:

```
count_words(word_string="this is an example sentence with a repeated word example", number_of_words=3)
```

which returns `[('example', 2), ('a', 1), ('an', 1)]`

I found the process of tuple sorting, quite tricky, and achieved it using `word_occurence_array.sort(key=lambda tup: (-tup[1], tup[0]))`. I was wondering if there are any other improvements that I can make to my overall code.

---

I hope this is a reasonable question - I've tweaked the description and example so that I hope it's not too easily identifiable.

Comment: If you feel that using a `Counter` as suggested by [200_success](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/118915/84718) would be "too easy" for this task, you might want to consider adding the tag [tag:reinventing-the-wheel].

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Good job on your first question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggestion made by 200_success is a good one if you don't care about the returned values in the case of a tie, however the question seems to indicate that after sorting by count, you should sort alphabetically. You'll need to add post-processing to that with a `Counter` (or any mapping). You could also do this with a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

def count_words2(word_string, number_of_words):
  words = word_string.split()
  word_dict = defaultdict(int)
  for word in words:
    word_dict[word] += 1

  return sorted(word_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda tup: (-tup[1], tup[0]))[:number_of_words]

def count_words3(word_string, number_of_words):    
  words = word_string.split()
  word_dict = Counter(words)
  return sorted(word_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda tup:(-tup[1], tup[0]))[:number_of_words]
```

My original answer was a bit hasty/knee-jerk reaction to the suggestion to use `most_common`, which gives no guarantees about ordering in the case of ties, nor can it be passed a function to handle the sorting. You can still use a `Counter`, you just can't use `most_common` without somewhat more complex post-processing.  As seen above, you should be able to use any mapping to actually get the frequency table, as the post-processing step will be the same. Given the lower complexity of `Counter`, that is still probably the best solution.

As suggested by Mathias Ettinger in the comments, you could also do something like this

```
class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict): pass

def count_words4(word_string, n):

  words = OrderedCounter(sorted(word_string.split()))
  return words.most_common(n)
```

In general I prefer to avoid multiple inheritance unless it is clearly a much cleaner and simpler solution than anything else - I don't think that is accurate in this case, but you might decide that it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly the kind of task that should be handled using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which offers a `most_common()` method to extract the results.

Comment: This won't necessarily work - the requirements are that ties be ordered alphabetically, while [`most_common` returns them arbitrarily](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common).

Comment: @Dannnno I didn't say that it's completely solved by `collections.Counter`. You would still want to do some post-processing.

Comment: Counter is available in python 2.7 https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 3):

Another thing I'd like to comment on (I only need to look at the start), so I'm copy/pasting that.

```
def count_words(word_string, number_of_words):
  """
  take in a word string and return a tuple of the
  most frequently counted words

  word_string = "This is an example sentence with a repeated word example",
  number_of_words = 3
  return [('example', 2), ('This', 1), ('a', 1)]
  """
```

First of all, the indent is 'wrong' (indenting in Python is traditionally 4 spaces).

Second, there's a traditional format for writing examples. It's called doctests. It looks just like the REPL.

```
def count_words(word_string, number_of_words):
    """
    take in a word string and return a tuple of the
    most frequently counted words.

    >>> word_string = "This is an example sentence with a repeated word example"
    >>> number_of_words = 3
    >>> count_words(word_string, number_of_words)
    [('example', 2), ('a', 1), ('an', 1)]
    """
    ... rest of code here ...
```

Then, using `python -m doctest -v modulename.py`, it will run your the parts prefixed by `>>>`, and check the output matches. I fixed the example, because the tie-resolution was not done properly in your example.